# Parse whole object with JSONStream.parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, jsonstream

I have an incoming JSON data object structure like this:

```
{
    foo: 3,
    bar: [
             {
                 key:value
             },
             {
                 key:value
             }
         ]
}
```

I want to treat foo one way, and bar another. But when I use JSONStream.parse("*") on the object, the first chunk it receives is "3".

Since the data objet is quite small, I want the streamer to return the whole object and I'll then manipulate it. I'd still like to use streams to be consistent with the rest of the project though. How do I force JSONStream to give me the whole object?

Comment: Why not `JSON`? `JSONStream` is not even a standard JavaScript object (you're probably using Node and that's a third-party package).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It is node. I want to be consistent with the way we fetch the rest of the data - at the moment they're called in a foreach with the pipe() function, and I'd rather use JSONStream than make the builder call it incostistently

Comment: If I read the [docs](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream) correctly, this is not possible. Looks like this package is exactly for partial parsing with pipelining results. If you want to get whole object, use `JSON` instead. It's two different tasks and I don't think you can achieve total "consistency" here (and you shouldn't)

Answer (score 1):

Its a little late but I have managed to do it like this:

```
let obj = {foo:{}, bar:[]}

const fooStream = JSONStream.parse(["foo", true]);
fooStream.on("data", (data)=>{obj.foo = data;})

const barStream = JSONStream.parse(["bar", true]);
barStream.on("data", (data)=>{obj.bar.push(data);})

_some_stream.pipe(fooStream);
_some_stream.pipe(barStream);
```